# Obtain text from a form/field of another application

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to import/extract the values of a form from another application to use in my code using python and pywin32.

With Spy++ I figured out the handles of the elements that I need to target, but I can't figure out how to obtain the text from the elements.

The way the target application is structured:

```
top app level
    (no name) class: MDIClient        (this is the centerWidget)
    (no name) class: ThunderRT6FormDC (occupies same space as centerwidget)
    (Ticket) class: ThunderRT6Frame  (Frame that holds all fields to extract from)
        (no name) class: NumEdit/DateEdit/TextEdit... (fields to import)
    (Information) class ThunderRT6Frame  (2nd frame with fields)
        (no name) class: NumEdit/DateEdit/TextEdit... (fields to import)
    (Process) class ThunderRT6Frame  (3rd frame with fields)
        (no name) class: NumEdit/DateEdit/TextEdit... (fields to import)
```

```
f = win32gui.FindWindow('ThunderRT6MDIForm', 'ApplicationName')
ex = win32gui.FindWindowEx(f, 0, 'MDIClient', None)
exx = win32gui.FindWindowEx(ex, 0, 'ThunderRT6FormDC', None)
exxx = win32gui.FindWindowEx(exx, 0, 'ThunderRT6Frame', None)
exxxx = win32gui.FindWindowEx(exxx, 0, 'NumEdit', None)
```

exxxx is the handle/element from which I want to extract the caption/text.
I'm sure FindWindowEx isn't the right function as it searches for Windows, but what function do I have to use?

Answer (score 1):

Starting by pointing out [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) which is a *Python* wrapper over *WinAPI*s. Documentation (*WiP*) can be found at [[GitHub.MHammond]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32) (or [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)).

[[MS.Learn]: FindWindowExW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexw) (wrapped by *win32gui.FindWindowEx*) should do the trick, if the relationship between 2 "consecutive" windows in the tree (e.g. *ex* and *exx*) is a **parent** - **child** one.

One other way would be to use [[MS.Learn]: EnumChildWindows function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) (*win32gui.EnumChildWindows*) - also check *EnumWindows*.
For more details, you could take a look at:

- [[SO]: Get the title of a window of another program using the process name (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31280850/4788546)
- [[SO]: Keyboard event not sent to window with pywin32 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54405186/4788546)

From there, you can use *GetWindowTextW* (*win32gui.GetWindowTextW*) to get the caption for the desired window.